# Match position of draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine you have 3 divs: foreground div, midground div and background div.
I want the foreground div to be draggable and when it is being dragged, the background div moves with it (like they are parent/child) but the midground div stays in place.

For what I am doing, these two can't be parented. Maybe there is a way for the background div to match the coordinates of the foreground div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works! I needed to adjust the position in CSS using margin-top and margin-left. But this works perfectly:

```
$("#div1").bind("drag", function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $("#div2").css({ left : offset.left, top: offset.top});
});
```